# DirectX and Xbox compatibility

Tags: c++, directx, game-development

I'm starting game development with DirectX and I was wondering if I somehow play games that I make on Xbox. I know you can use Xbox controller controls, but only on computer (as I know).

Answer (score 3):

Xbox One supports a "Developer mode" which runs UWP applications written for DirectX 11 or DirectX 12. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/)

See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-and-uwp-on-xbox-one/) for some additional notes.

To sum up:

- For UWP on Xbox One, only x64 native apps are supported
- Direct3D 11 with `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0` is supported
- Direct3D 12 with `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_0` is supported in 'game mode' only
- Direct3D 9 or earlier is not supported.

For UWP development you do NOT use the [legacy DirectX SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-) or the [deprecated D3DX](https://walbourn.github.io/living-without-d3dx/) library.

- Game controllers are accessed via **Windows.Gaming.Input**, and there is an XINPUT emulation library you can use `xinput_uap.lib`. DirectInput is not supported.
- XAudio2 is supported. DirectSound and XACT are not supported.

> If you are looking to learn low-level graphics in C++ see [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started). This library is supported for UWP apps including UWP on Xbox One as well as Win32 desktop apps on Windows 7 or later. The UWP templates at [directx-vs-templates](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates) work for UWP on Xbox One.

There are a number of UWP samples on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples) which will run on UWP for Xbox One.

> Unity can also be used to target [UWP on Xbox One](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/development-lanes-unity)